# Can't install scikit-learn in Python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, scikit-learn

Hi I'm trying to install scikit-learn in Python on a mac, but failed. Does anyone having idea how to fix this? Thanks! The error message is as follows.

**Error message**

> Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UfI2WG-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/yuxinsun/Library/Logs/pip.log

**pip.log is like this. (sorry i have to change a little for links in pip.log since i can't attach more than 2 links, but i think the links are not so crucial)**

/usr/local/bin/pip run on Sun Mar 23 02:25:36 2014

Downloading/unpacking scikit-learn

Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/

URLs to search for versions for scikit-learn:

- link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/

  Analyzing links from page link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/

  Skipping link link - pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.10.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=eae1e20fc4d7ebc3ec2d1c31cb5eb1a5 (from link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/); unknown archive format: .exe

  Skipping link link - pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.11.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=d585305053461699b48ffbb176a16ca8 (from link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/); unknown archive format: .exe

  Skipping link link - pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.12.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=0a352a8087c581d4c75cc2ad4ec043b2 (from link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/); unknown archive format: .exe

  Skipping link link - pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.12.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=3fdb37b8754167fb2ddde035306cf4ae (from link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/); unknown archive format: .exe

  Skipping link link - pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.13.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=6fcfd76f705f30c4fabaece0832026fc (from link - pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/); unknown archive format: .exe

@
"~/Library/Logs/pip.log" 1413L, 93793C

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error with `pip install -U scikit-learn` on Ubuntu 14.04. I believe it's an insufficient permissions issue on the file `/private/tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn/setup.py`. I resolved it by elevating permissions on pip with `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade pip from 7.1.2 to 8.1 and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have installed scikit-learn by the following method.

```
    $ pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practise to set up an environment to do this. Anaconda (or Miniconda) handles the requirements/dependencies pretty well.