# Why is Scikit-learn package not installing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to utilize the Python library Scikit-Learn on my Raspberry Pi 2 for machine learning. I have used `pip install scikit-learn`, `pip3 install scikit-learn`, and `pip install -U scikit-learn`. When I try, this message comes up:

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-vOeVw5/scikit-
>   learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
>   (**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,     **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-yngTA7-record/install-record.txt     --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in     /tmp/pip-build-vOeVw5/scikit-learn/

So how can I get this library active? I'd aprecciate any help.

Comment: Looks like a similar error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586396/cant-install-scikit-learn-in-python

Comment: How so? Correct me if I'm wrong, but OSX is much more different from Raspbian.

Comment: Just look at the error output

Comment: And the answer there  was in Ubuntu, which is Debian based like Rasbian

Comment: I see what you intended me to see, however, I have tried everything but the github install. I have a question, is it the exact same library?

Comment: If its from github?

Comment: That is the official scikit-learn repository, yes. It's just bundled and put where pip has access to it if you don't specify Github

Comment: Even the github way came up with error code 1.

Comment: Try using sudo, yet?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I have.